# flutter run vs. right click run

Tags: flutter, testing

I have a test file that needs to be ran on a device as opposed to the emulator. This is the test:

```
@GenerateMocks([GeolocatorWrapper, PermissionsWrapper])

void main() {

  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  group('LocationPresenter', () {
    test('setZipCodeFromLocation properly uses location zip code if permission is always granted', () async {
      final MockGeolocatorWrapper mockGeolocatorWrapper = MockGeolocatorWrapper();
      final MockPermissionsWrapper mockPermissionsWrapper = MockPermissionsWrapper();
      final LocationPresenter presenter = LocationPresenter(mockGeolocatorWrapper, mockPermissionsWrapper);

      when(mockPermissionsWrapper.request()).thenAnswer((_)  => Future.value(PermissionStatus.granted));
      when(mockGeolocatorWrapper.getCurrentPosition()).thenAnswer((_)  => Future.value(
          Position.fromMap({'latitude': 36.5157, 'longitude': -82.2570, 'timestamp': 0})
      ));

      await presenter.setZipCodeFromLocation();

      expect(presenter.getZipCodeFromLocation(), "37620");
    });

    test('setZipCodeFromLocation properly uses location zip code if permission is while ine use', () async {
      final MockGeolocatorWrapper mockGeolocatorWrapper = MockGeolocatorWrapper();
      final MockPermissionsWrapper mockPermissionsWrapper = MockPermissionsWrapper();
      final LocationPresenter presenter = LocationPresenter(mockGeolocatorWrapper, mockPermissionsWrapper);

      when(mockPermissionsWrapper.request()).thenAnswer((_)  => Future.value(PermissionStatus.granted));
      when(mockGeolocatorWrapper.getCurrentPosition()).thenAnswer((_)  => Future.value(
          Position.fromMap({'latitude': 36.5157, 'longitude': -82.2570, 'timestamp': 0})
      ));

      await presenter.setZipCodeFromLocation();

      expect(presenter.getZipCodeFromLocation(), "37620");
    });

  });

}
```

If I run it using flutter run /path/to/test, it runs fine. If I right click on the file in the tree and either select "run tests in..." or run ...", it fails with these errors:

```
lib/model/configs/scavengedConfigs/siteSpecific/AA/factories/results/AAActionUrlPartResultFactory.dart:19:34: Warning: Operand of null-aware operation '!' has type 'Element' which excludes null.
 - 'Element' is from 'package:html/dom.dart' ('/C:/Users/Gossling/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/html-0.15.4/lib/dom.dart').
    if (resultsScript != null && resultsScript!.nodes.isNotEmpty) {
                                 ^
/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:9:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' as ui show Canvas, Paint, Path;
       ^
Context: The unavailable library 'dart:ui' is imported through these packages:

    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter => dart:ui
    ...

Detailed import paths for (some of) the these imports:

    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/memory_allocations.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/memory_allocations.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/change_notifier.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/memory_allocations.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/key.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/memory_allocations.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/memory_allocations.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/memory_allocations.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/scheduler.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/scheduler.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/priority.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/scheduler.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/priority.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/scheduler.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/priority.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/assertions.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    LocationPresenter_test.dart => package:flutter/material.dart => package:flutter/src/material/about.dart => package:flutter/scheduler.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/scheduler/priority.dart => package:flutter/foundation.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart => package:flutter/src/foundation/debug.dart => dart:ui
    ...

/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/animated_icons.dart:10:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
       ^
/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/arc.dart:6:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/badge_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/banner_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_app_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^
/D:/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/bottom_navigation_bar_theme.dart:5:8: Error: Dart library 'dart:ui' is not available on this platform.
import 'dart:ui' show lerpDouble;
       ^

Process finished with exit code 254
```

I would have thought that both of these methods of running the test/file would be equal, but I guess not. I also modified the run configuration to add "-d Pixel6a" but that did not work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!